# Execute an .exe from a remote server

Tags: c#, networking

i want write a c# program which must run on my pc an exe application but the exe is on a windows 2008 server with authentification in the same domain

I'm trying some google codes (WMI)  but it's not working now. Can you help me?

Comment: You'll get a better response if you post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to answer, because threre are a lot of ways to solve this problem.

An easy way is you write an windows service which use a self hosted web api to communicate with the world. Your second program on your desktop computer speeks over http with your windows service on your windows server 2008. Than you can implement a method with the name `startProgram` or something like this.